# How can I add/show current application icon or Ubuntu icon on left of Unity panel?

Tags: unity, panel

I was wondering if we can put Ubuntu or current (focused) application icon in Unity panel on left like Mac.

[image]

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thank you.

Comment: please do not rollback again.  If you have additional information please edit this into the current version.  If you disagree with the current edit, please drop a comment here explaining what issue you have.

Comment: mister Foss if u have an answer please answer ti the question, changing the grammar would not solve the problem, 
the one who has understood has already answered me.

Comment: Please look at my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62940/what-is-the-reason-for-moving-the-dash-button-in-11-10 and also look at this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70072/can-i-put-the-ubuntu-button-on-the-top-panel-instead-of-the-launcher

Answer (score 0):

As of 12.04, that functionality is honestly impossible. Unity is not coded that way. If you've used 11.04, there was the Ubuntu logo there before. That has been removed.

Comment: hmm, well thank you, there are some more problems like transparent panel gradient effect, no blur for transparent panel
there is [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/963649) i am still waiting to get solved

gnome 3 looks very bad, gnome with 10.10 was awesome. unity is good but has some bugs.